# Fade out bootstrap modal using jquery/css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form inside a bootstrap modal. I awake it using jQuery
    $(modalId).modal('show');

I don't want it to be fade in. So, I didn't add 'fade' class to my modal. upon submitting the form in modal. I want to fade out the modal.

```
$(modalId).modal('hide');
```

I used the above code segment to hide the modal, it works. But, the modal goes out very quickly. I want it to  fade out for a few seconds. How can I achieve it?

My code:

```
$('.save').on('click', function(){
 setTimeout(function(){

  $('#div_dbReadMany').modal("hide");

 }, 1500);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jffasna/puLqdhyc/5/)

Comment: Do you want this using css animation?

Comment: Anyways, My target is to fade out. No problem with css

Comment: To solve this with effect you should use css animation / transition. It's not a matter of jquery or js at all.

Comment: Can u provide an example? with my fiddle above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution by adding a delay to fadeout the modal and increased the time out on

```
$(modalId).modal('hide');
```

Code is here:

```
 $('.save').on('click', function(){

  $('#div_dbReadMany').delay(1000).fadeOut(450);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div_dbReadMany').modal("hide");
  }, 1500);

 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code.

```
$('.save').on('click', function(){
   $('#div_dbReadMany').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
   setTimeout(function() {
       $("#div_dbReadMany").modal('hide');
   }, 1500);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/puLqdhyc/6/)

Comment: see the fiddle, I've added it. But, after the timeout it goes sudden. I don't want it to go like that. I want it to go fade out

Comment: Try now and see demo.

Comment: OP answered her own question, looks like your edit is just a copy of that.